# Binding Drop Down List from Code behind using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to bind drop-down box from code behind, but I am getting a compilation error:

> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource'

I have tried to figure out but cannot seem to fix this issue.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MYDDL" Width="300px" DataTextField="PRJ_TITLE" AutoPostBack="true"
                  DataValueField="PRJ_ID" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is my function:

```
private void Bind_DD()
{
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT  ID, PRJ_TITLE FROM myTable");

    cmd1.Connection = con2;
    con2.Open();

    myDDL.DataSource = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    myDDL.DataTextField = "PRJ_TITLE";
    myDDL.DataValueField = "ID";
    myDDL.DataBind();

    con2.Close();

}
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code. In the current snippet there is no `SqlDataSource` control mentioned.

Comment: Why are you databinding twice?

Comment: Andrei, i don't have sql datasource in the aspx that is why i was trying to bind it in the code behind.  I am not sure what am i doing wrong here.  thanks

Comment: Josh, u just updated my code. thanks

Comment: @moe, what was the code in the first case? And what is the problem with code-behind approach?

Comment: it was the same and the problem is in the code behind

Comment: is it normal that your control's `ID` is `MYDDL` (uppercase) and in your code behind you are setting the `DataSource` of `myDDL` (2 first characters in lowercase) ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like you are possibily a bit mixed up about sql data connections as there are many ways to do them. I elected to do a databing via the sqlDataAdapter to DataTable.

Additionally make sure you do not have any elements in your markup that have a asp:SqlDataSource anywhere in your markup.

```
private void Bind_DD()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using(SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con2.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT  ID, PRJ_TITLE FROM myTable",con2);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }

    myDDL.DataSource = dt;
    myDDL.DataTextField = "PRJ_TITLE";
    myDDL.DataValueField = "ID";
    myDDL.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void Bind_DD()
{
    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT  ID, PRJ_TITLE FROM myTable");
    cmd1.Connection = con2;
    con2.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    sda.Fill(ds);
    myDDL.DataSource = ds; //cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    myDDL.DataTextField = "PRJ_TITLE";
    myDDL.DataValueField = "ID";
    myDDL.DataBind();
    con2.Close();
    //myDDL.DataBind(); 
 }
```